# Drupal 8 - taxonomy term field without "title" attribute

Tags: views, theming

I have a simple view block with exposed the taxonomy term linked to the taxonomy page, but I have noticed that the attribute is missing, I tried to rewrite the term but every attempt went wrong.

What I need is simple, this is the view generated field:

```
<a href="/category/events" tabindex="-1">Events</a>
```

I want to add `title="Events"`, like this:

```
<a href="/category/events" tabindex="-1" title="Events">Events</a>
```

But I can't find any solutions in Drupal 8 view!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're adding the title attribute, but I don't think the example you've given is the intended way to use for it.

Comment: Hi sonfd, I want to add the title for accessibility, a requirement that WCAG requires. 
https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html

Comment: Is your TITLE coming from VIEW or Its the default taxonomy page with TITLE?

Comment: From the page you linked to "Because of the extensive user agent limitations in supporting access to the title attribute, authors should use caution in applying this technique. For this reason, it is preferred that the author use technique C7: Using CSS to hide a portion of the link text (CSS) or H30: Providing link text that describes the purpose of a link for anchor elements."

Comment: Hi Ajay Reddy, the title i coming from VIEW, view generated field!

Comment: sonfd ok, but i want the title="XXX", then I'll put a description, the one above is just an example!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [template_preprocess_views_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_field/8.5.x) to accomplish this. Create that hook in your custom theme like:

```
/**
 * Alter field_MY_TAX_FIELD link to add title attribute.
 *
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view_field().
 */
function MY_THEME_preprocess_views_view_field(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['field']->field == 'field_MY_TAX_FIELD') {
    // Add title attribute to link.
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could create a new field formatter that extends [Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\EntityReferenceLabelFormatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21EntityReferenceLabelFormatter.php/class/EntityReferenceLabelFormatter/8.5.x). Override the `viewElements` method. First call `$elements = parent::viewElements($items, $langcode);`, then traverse `$elements` and add your title attribute when appropriate. After you create the formatter, clear cache and then go back to your view and select your new formatter as formatter for the taxonomy field.